# RadGrid not showing input controls while loading using ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, telerik, radgrid

I have a Telerik RadGrid inside usercontrol in ASP.Net C#. It works fine if I load that usercontrol directly in .aspx page. But when I use RadPages and load that usercontrol using RadAjax request it is not showing Input controls in grid.
I also tried loading usercontrol by using JQuery Ajax request but in that case also result is same.

Without Ajax Call
[image]

With Ajax Call
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed RadFormDecorator from user control and it works.